# without applicationDidFinishLaunching in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I've many classes in my XCode project, and only the class from where the control comes from main.m will be having **applicationDidFinishlaunching** method. in my other classes will the methods in it knows how to go to its own method implementation, or do i need to write init method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about, but I will try.. :-)

applicationDidFinishLaunching is part of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. Typically, only one class will implement this protocol in one application.

In you other classes, you implement the init method if you need to do something when an instance of that class is created, like instantiating and initializing property values for that instance.